# Ender 3 filament retracts on its own

Tags: extruder, filament, retraction

While printing flat surfaces the filament would begin to retract by itself, even if the printer is actively extruding it. I've been remedying it by occasionally pushing the filament by hand, has anyone had this issue in the past or has any idea how to fix it?

- Slicer: Cura v.5.4.0
- Retraction: off
- Flow rate: 75% (calibrated after installing new extruder)
- Printer: Ender 3
- Leveling done via BLTouch (Z offset calibrated to be 0.1 mm from print bed)
- E steps calibrated properly
- Hotend temp: 200 °C
- Print bed temp: 50 °C
- Filament type: PLA
- Filament brand: Creality grey 1 kg

Comment: You have given us statements but have not asked a question or told us what settings you are using. Without additional information, this "question" could be closed.

Comment: Sorry about that, added details now and asked a proper question. If there are any details that I left out let me know and I'll update ASAP

Comment: Probably a typo, please clarify the version of Cura that you are using.

Comment: When properly calibrated, the flow modifier is about 100 %. It is better to adjust the steps per mm rather than editing the flow modifier.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if your nozzle is too close to the bed (too low Z-offset). Check your first layer thickness. It should be a slightly squished bead. Not a smeared line.

When the nozzle is too close to the bed, the filament can't come out and the extruder skips steps. When a bowden extruder skips steps, the filament is actually retracted a bit because of the tension built up in the tube.